# Hard drive issue with HFS and windows

Tags: hard-drive

I've got a problem with some hard drives. I've had some issues with my MBP and I'm unable to access my account on the computer. (I've been told its a graphical issue with the GPU, it keeps crashing before logging on) I've verified and repaired the disk on the macbook and it says its all great.

Problem is that I have a few confidential files that I need to access quickly and the drive wont show the OSX partition on my windows computer. It shows up as a unknown partition in the Disk management. The windows partition (From bootcamp) shows up in my computer and as a NTFS partition in Disk management. I've tried installing apples bootcamp registry folders to allow my computer to read the disk, I've also gotten paragon HFS+ and HFSExplorer. Nothing comes up.

I would appreciate some help on how I can gain access to my files once more as I really do need to access them urgently. Ideally at no cost (Sending in to HDD specialists etc)

Comment: As I read this the mac with the broken GPU does boot... So you might be able to start it up start it up while holding down the T key. This will turn it into an external drive. All you need is another Mac (or a PC) to copy access it.

Comment: Yes it does boot. It crashes whenever I try and log in and if left for 5-10 mins it will overheat and power down. How do I gain access to the files from my other computer? My desktop doesn't have firewire or thunderbolt you see.

Comment: I best answer that witha link: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH10725?locale=en_US   
No FireWire or Thunderbolt might make that hard though. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try to access the files thru the single user mode of your Mac:

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201573

From here on:

- Find the name of your drive by typing "`ls /Volumes`" in the terminal
- Run "`sbin/mount -uw/`" to try to mount the drive.
- To fix any filesystem errors, use "`sbin/fsck -fy`"
- If all works out, you can use the cp command to start copying the files